# modulus operator in ruby case when

Tags: ruby, case, modulus

I was trying to do the following in code and not sure how to use the modulus with case when

```
(1..100).each do |number|
  case number
    when % 3 and % 5
      puts "Hello World"
    when % 3
      puts "Hello"
    when % 5
      puts "World"
    else
      puts number
   end
end
```

I know I am just missing something dumb, but no idea what that is.

Edit: just changed it to how it would have to work.

Comment: `when number % 3 == 0`

Comment: If you're trying to implement FizzBuzz, this is incorrect implementation.

Comment: Or, (what you meant by) your condition `% 3 and % 5` is redundant since it will never be evaluated to be true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably write it something like this. It's an old-school thing:

```
(1..15).each do |number|
  case
  when (number % 3 == 0) && (number % 5 == 0)
    puts "(#{ number }) Hello World"
  when (number % 3 == 0)
    puts "(#{ number }) Hello"
  when (number % 5 == 0)
    puts "(#{ number }) World"
  else
    puts number
  end
end

# >> 1
# >> 2
# >> (3) Hello
# >> 4
# >> (5) World
# >> (6) Hello
# >> 7
# >> 8
# >> (9) Hello
# >> (10) World
# >> 11
# >> (12) Hello
# >> 13
# >> 14
# >> (15) Hello World
```

---

Here's how I'd really write it:

```
(1..15).each do |number|
  val = case
        when (number % 3 == 0) && (number % 5 == 0)
          "Hello World"
        when (number % 3 == 0)
          "Hello"
        when (number % 5 == 0)
          "World"
        else
          number
        end

  puts val
end
```

This is cleaner and even more readable. While it's possible to use `case 0`, the tests for each `when` become less easily understood, which is a prime consideration when we write code. We write for at least two people, ourselves at the moment, and for whoever is maintaining it in the future. It needs to make sense at all times, so the more obvious and clean the code is, the faster it'll enter the brain when it's read in a couple years, reducing debugging time and the work-load on the future you.

Comment: It is good to know that case can be used without anything.  This is more accurate of an answer (even without the output of the numbers in the strings).

Comment: Those were just to make it easier to check the results. I'll add how I'd actually write it if it was my code.

Answer (score 1):

I believe `case` is for the situations where you need to compare the result of **one** expression to **multiple** values.

Here you have several expressions `number % 3`, `number % 5` and `number % 15` compared to one value `0`. I would suggest using `if-elsif-else` here:

```
if number % 15 == 0
  puts 'Hello World'
elsif number % 3 == 0
  puts 'Hello'
elsif number % 5 == 0
  puts 'World'
else
  puts number
end
```

Or consider reversing the idea of this comparison and making `0` the expression itself:

```
case 0
when number % 15
  puts "Hello World"
when number % 3
  puts "Hello"
when number % 5
  puts "World"
else
  puts number
end
```

I prefer the former solution. More straightforward and one less line.

p.s. I personally think that expressionless `case`-s are ugly :)

Answer (score -1):

The below will work :

```
(1..15).each do |number|
  case 0
    when number%3 + number%5
      puts "Hello World"
    when number % 3
      puts "Hello"
    when number % 5
      puts "World"
    else
      puts number
   end
end

# >> 1
# >> 2
# >> Hello
# >> 4
# ...
# >> 13
# >> 14
# >> Hello World
```

FYI: Moved the third condition to be the first - otherwise it would never be reached.

Comment: I didn't down rate your answer but the 3rd condition doesn't work.

Comment: @TobyJoiner I tried to just taught OP, where did he mistake. What should be the structure. I don't know why he wrote such code,as OP didn't mention that. He just said - *I know I am just missing something dumb, but no idea what that is.*.. So I did correct it.

Comment: I am the OP.  I just realized that the 3rd condition should have been first.  I don't know how to make the 3rd one work if I made it the first one, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @TobyJoiner Sorry I didn't see your name :))

Comment: Thank you, that fixed it.  I appreciate the answer.

Comment: **Down-voter** would you please answer to this post,so that I can see what wrong I did. If you don't post any answer,then please don't create any noise. )

Comment: Code in your answer does not work as expected. What do you think should be output for 5?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev fire me then,by saying wrong incorrect points please.

Comment: If the OP is testing for values that are evenly divisible by 3, 5 AND 3 and 5, then neither 5 or 10 should output "Hello World". Only a value for 15 should output "Hello World"

Comment: @ArupRakshit edited again, Hope you're OK with it (if not, revert :). Modified the first condition to be the sum of both modulo operations.

Comment: I think the current version of the answer should meet the conditions (it works and outputs what we think the OP wants). Are there any reasons left for the downvotes?

Answer (score -2):

```
(1..100).each do |number|
  puts case number
  when ->x{x.%(3).zero? and x.%(5).zero?}
    "Hello World"
  when ->x{x.%(3).zero?}
    "Hello"
  when ->x{x.%(5).zero?}
    "World"
  else
    number
  end
end
```

Comment: This is the only correct implementation, but man, is it convoluted?

Comment: You mean the chain notation? I thought you were going to say something about it.

Comment: Oh, and BTW, use `&&` instead of `and` here :)

Comment: No, I meant lambdas in whens. But dot notation too :)

Comment: It can be either `&&` or `and`. I prefer `and` because natural language words are easier to read than symbols.

Comment: Is there an alternative to lambdas?

Comment: Given that we have to use `case/when`? Can't think of anything right now. But best approach is, naturally, plain ifs with regular modulo checks.

Comment: RE `&&` vs `and`: that will bite you in the ass one day. They have different precedence. Use `&&` for conditions, `and` for control flow only.

Comment: Regarding `case/when`, I agree. The question narrowed down the possibilities.

Comment: `and` and `or` has stronger precedence than conditional words like `if`, `unless`, so it does not become a problem. And in this case, it is inside the lambda block anyway.

Comment: not *that* control flow. Think Perl/PHP's: `do "something" or die`

Comment: +1 @SergioTulentsev, having come to Ruby from Perl, I am always thinking about the `or` situation and precedence. And using parenthesis liberally to make sure the interpreter and I agree that my way is right.